# In a right triangle, given slope and length of hypotenuse find length of legs.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Say I have a right triangle.

[image: right triangle]

I know the slope and length of $c$, how do I find the length of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You "know the slope of $c$" in what way?  Are you given an angle, or a "rise/run" fraction?

Comment: Use the slope of $c$ to find the angle at $A$.

Comment: No need for trigonometry here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a right triangle, so there are two things we know:

- Slope $\;m = \dfrac{a - 0}{b-0}=\dfrac ab\implies a = bm$.

And

- $a^2 + b^2 = \underbrace{c^2}_{\text{hypotenuse}}$

Two equations and two unknowns.

**SPOILER ALERT:**

> Since $a = bm, $ we can substitute $bm$ into the variable $a$ in the second equation: $$(bm)^2 + b^2 = c^2\implies b^2(m^2 + 1) = c^2 \implies b^2 = \dfrac{c^2}{m^2 + 1} \implies b = \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}}.$$  Since the lengths of the sides of a triangle must be positive, we can take the positive root of $b^2$ to solve for $b$, then back substitute to obtain $a = bm$.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the "slope"
$$m = \frac ab$$
then you can write $a$ as $mb$. Fit this in
$$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$
and get
$$b = \frac{c}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

if you kno9w the overall slope, but maybe you want to find the Y value of a shorter distance for x, use these relations.

where F is the hypotenuse, X is the x value, and Y is the Y value. 
Fcos(angle)=X,
Fsin(angle)=Y,
which you probably have memorized, but here are the ones you've forgotten.

Xtan(angle)=Y,
Ycot(angle)=X,

Comment: If you are going to discard the notation $a,b,c$ introduced in the Question, you should provide definitions for your unknowns $X,Y$.  I can accept that $F$ is your hypotenuse (where the OP labels the length of hypotenuse $c$), but you have mentioned "slope" and "angle" without definition (or referring to the original quantities).

Answer (score 0):

$m = \frac{a}{b}$

If you take your simplified $a$ and $b$, and use $a^2+b^2=c^2$, you can do $\frac{hypotenuse}{c}$ to get the scaling factor. Once you have your scaling factor, put your slope into fraction form.

Multiply your numerator by the scaling factor and you will get $a$. Multiply your denominator by the scaling factor and you will get $b$.

Comment: I don't see that you've added anything useful to the Accepted Answer from almost three years ago.  When responding to an older Question, you will help your Readers by highlighting any new information you have.